# Is it possible to grant security roles through an event receiver?

Tags: permissions, security, active-directory

I have a requirement to grant a department contribute to their department parent & child sites.  The catch is, they also want to be able to grant & remove contribute to outside department users.  If I were to create a field called "Contribute Members" to a list on a site, could I have an event receiver grant/remove AD users contribute when the form is saved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, you could.

Some key articles for you to start with:

1. [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivilegies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx) - this will allow you to elevate privilegies for current user
2. [SPFieldUserValue and SPFieldUserValueCollection](http://www.sharepointkings.com/2009/04/spfielduservalue-and.html) - these classes will help you to extract values from "Person or group" column.
3. [SPWeb.EnsureUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spweb.ensureuser.aspx) - will help you to ensure that AD user is added to a site
4. [SPGroup.AddUser method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms454048.aspx) - will allow you to add users to SharePoint groups of a site, providing appropriate privilegies to them

Feel free to ask, if you need more details for any step.

Answer (score 1):

That is one of the common uses of Event Receivers : to take actions the users themselves might not be able to do due to UI or security restrictions.

Comment: sounds great in theory, right!